# Hibernate Resetting Database Columns to Default Value?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am trying to replicate and diagnose a user's problem, so please bear with me.  I have not been able to replicate the issue myself.

Let "User" be a Plain Old Java Object (POJO):  a class in Java and a table in SQL.  My speculation/suspicion is if you run the following inside a Hibernate transaction:

```
User user = (User) hsi.s.load(User.class, userId);
user.setProperty(value);  // this updates one value in this row of the database table
```

then Hibernate or SQL sometimes resets properties of "User" to their default values.  This is the only explanation I can fathom for what I am seeing, although I admit that I can't reproduce the issue myself.

Has anyone heard of such a thing happening, where Hibernate or SQL resets a property to its default value?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried doing session.saveorupdate(user); after modifying the POJO values?

Comment: Patton, saveOrUpdate shouldn't be necessary, since the object is already associated with a Hibernate session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's hard to say "no", as it's harder to prove that something doesn't exists than to prove that something exists, but I'm confident that this is the right answer :-) Unless you have code that sets the fields back to their default values, Hibernate will always honor what you have in your database. Meaning, if you have really a POJO that doesn't extends any other class, that has nothing in the default no-arg constructor, that the only thing it does is to provide getters/setters to properties and that no other code by you (listeners, for instance) changes it, then there's no way Hibernate is setting the values "back" to their default values.

If this is really happening, here are my suggestions on how to find the problematic code:

1) Setup a new project, with a simple persistence.xml file, your pojo, and a Java class that can be run from the command line and that would retrieve, print and update a property in your pojo. The values should *not* be reset to the default values, if the non-default values are defined. If that's still happening, check your database for triggers.

2) Download Hibernate sources and start a debugger. Step into every instruction, except those that involves the JVM (those won't be of much help in this case). Perhaps you'll find a listener somewhere, or a code in a helper, or something else is being executed that you are not aware.